# Image not found error after packaging electron with native module

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I created c++ native module and there is also a third party library "sample.dylib". After running command *node-gyp configure* and *node-gyp build* and then *npm start*, the application runs fine. But when I package the app for distribution and run the app, I get the error.

Below is my binding.gyp:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "mylib",

      "link_settings": {
        "libraries": [ 
          "../sample.dylib"
        ] 
      },
      "sources": [ "mylib_wrap.cxx"],      
      'cflags_cc': [
      '-std=c++0x',
      '-fexceptions',
      '-Wall',
      '-O3'
    ],
    'xcode_settings': {
      'CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD': 'c++11',
      'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY': 'libc++',
      'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET': '10.7',
      'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS': 'YES',
      'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_RTTI': 'YES',
      'OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS': [
        '-fexceptions',
        '-Wall',
        '-O3'
      ]
    },
    }
  ]
}
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: 

dlopen(/Users/<user-name>/Development/electron-quick-

    start/dist/mac/electron-quick-start.app/Contents/Resources/app/build/Release/mylib.node, 1): Library not loaded: sample.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/<user-name>/Development/electron-quick-start/dist/mac/electron-quick-start.app/Contents/Resources/app/build/Release/mylib.node
      Reason: image not found
```